# How do I style the first list item in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am generating a list using jquery-ui autocomplete. I would like to apply a custom class to this list so that I can refer to the first item in this list using a css selector like my_list:first-child.

I have tried the following code, but the class specifier on the li tag is being lost. Any suggestions? The similar questions on here talk about overloading renderItem with monkey patching but given all I want to do is specify a class attribute this seems excessive.

```
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = ( ul, item ) ->
  $( "<li class='my_list'></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( '<a>' + item.label + '</a>' )
    .appendTo( ul )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you take a deep look [of the output](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), you will get something like:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; display: block; width: 108px; top: 275px; left: 576px; ">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" tabindex="-1" id="ui-active-menuitem">ActionScript</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AppleScript</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Asp</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">BASIC</a></li>
</ul>
```

for such, a style like:

```
.ui-autocomplete li:first-child { background-color: red; }
```

will do the trick:

[image]

*Am I missing something on your question?*